# ApplicationPool ProcessModel Identity fails when installed via cmd line

Tags: wcf, service, cmd

I have a WCF service which I install via cmd line, due to installment on many servers!

When installing application pool and configuring it, I set a custom account on the process model identity, which is just an account with local administrator rights!

But when I try to browse the service just to see the front service page I get a Service Unavailable message with http error 503, which is a server error which again comes from an event id 5021, which states that the identity for the service's application pool is invalid due to either incorrect username/password or the user may not have batch logon rights.

Ergo, the error has to do with the user identity! When I change Identity to NetworkService there is no problem. I cannot either manually set the Identity to the user...

My cmd line looks like:

c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /name:"calendarproviderservice" ^
    /autostart:"true" ^
    /managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" ^
    /processModel.idleTimeout:"24:00:00" ^
    /enable32BitAppOnWin64:"true" ^
    /processmodel.identitytype:"SpecificUser"  ^
    /processModel.userName:"PlannerAdmin"

Anyone has a clue...?

Cheers, Finn.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I finally solved my problem! Unfortunately I didn't sketch the hole scenario in the main question because I didn't think it mattedered in the context. But it did!

The scenario was that my server was a deployed server with a base configuration including IIS 7.5! And this is the problem!

When you try to set the application pool identity to a domain account, IIS has to keep a local copy of your username and password. This is stored in IIS applicationHost.config in encrypted format. In the encryption IIS uses the machine specific keys in iisConfiguration and iisWasKey containers. When this applicationHost.config is moved to a different server (in this case the deployed server on new hardware), IIS can no longer decrypt the password because of the new machine keys.

One can export configuration Keys, but I already deleted the base server I made an image of!

So the lesson learned here is: If you have to deploy many servers with IIS on, make a base image WITHOUT IIS, and script the IIS on the server after deployment!!!

Cheers, Finn.

PS. Dominik, sorry that I wasn't that clear on the intro question!

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned the user to the local IIS_USRS group?

Comment: Did you check that the account was not disabled by accident? Further you dont supply a password with your command, did you remove it before posting?

Comment: No, that's right I don't supply a password there! I could not find a way to supply it! The account is not disabled....!

Comment: Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(WS.10).aspx, I think you can specify the password using /processModel.password:"mypass"

Comment: Hmm...Yes I can apparently set a password as well, but now I get an error: hresult:80090016, message: Failed to commit configuration changes. Keyset does not exist. What does this mean...? This error comes only when specifying the password. Without this specified the username gets filled in, but does not work and refers to the error that I wrote in the start question...

Comment: Have you tried running your script with administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes, sir! With local administrator privileges, as the server is not member of any domain at this point!

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using an account having administrator privileges, or did you start the command prompt (or whatever you´re using to host your cmd) using right click -> run as administrator. Note that this makes a difference assuming you´re running Win7/Server2008

Comment: I'm running the script when logged on as local administrator. The script starts the cmd prompt, so I'm not using "run as administrator". One of the first thing the script does, is to create a new user "PlannerAdmin" and then adds the user to the administrators group! The server is Windows Server 2008R2.

Comment: I think we should take this into chat if we have to continue. Whatever the first step is, triggering your script, run this step "as administrator"

Comment: Hmm...It seems that running cmd line "as administrator" doesn't have any effect. I still come up with keyset error and hresult: 80090016...Irritating...Thanks for your effort, though, Dominik!